# Does CWindowImpl use CRTP for calling the windows procedure?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, crtp

I was under the impression that in order to use the curiously recurring template pattern, there had to be some static down-casting of the `this` pointer into the derived class.

But in `CWindowImplBaseT`, `ProcessWindowMessage` is called as follows:

```
template <class TBase, class TWinTraits>
LRESULT CALLBACK CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >::WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >* pThis = (CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >*)hWnd;
    // set a ptr to this message and save the old value
    _ATL_MSG msg(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    const _ATL_MSG* pOldMsg = pThis->m_pCurrentMsg;
    pThis->m_pCurrentMsg = &msg;
    // pass to the message map to process
    LRESULT lRes = 0;
    BOOL bRet = pThis->ProcessWindowMessage(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, lRes, 0);
   //. . .
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any static casting into the application-declared derived class (which is provided by template in `CWindowImpl`).  So does that mean this class is not getting the advantage or CRTP?

Comment: There is no CRTP here. `ProcessWindowMessage` might have something there - logically, this is where one would expect to call the method of the derived class. But I am not familiar with ATL.

Comment: Not CRTP. ProcessWindowMessage is a virtual method.

Comment: @RaymondChen So doesn't that hurt performance?  Especially since that function gets called millions of times?  I saw Jim Springfield say that with ATL they didn't want to leave any performance on the table.

Comment: I suspect that adding three instructions to message dispatch is unlikely to be noticeable, seeing as message dispatch takes tens of thousands of cycles already.

Comment: *"Not leaving any performance on the table"* meant something different in the 90s than it does today.

Comment: So is a lot of CRTP usage unnecessary now?  Granted, I'm just learning and don't know what I'm talking about, but I would've thought if there were ever a time to use the CRTP, it would be when calling that windows procedure a gazillion times.

Comment: The CRTP (more generally known as F-bound polymorphism) replaces runtime dispatch with compile time dispatch, which is always desirable. For an implementation to take advantage of the CRTP, that pattern must be known and template support in compilers must be widely available. At least the latter wasn't a given in the 90s, and I'm not sure about the former. Though the window procedure isn't actually called a gazillion times, so things aren't as bad as you think.